# How to access Send or Cancel buttons in MFMailComposeViewController even though it's evil

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've seen a lot of similar questions being asked on SO, but every answer is "the apple docs say don't do that." Still, I can't help but think it's possible through private APIs to do this. Anyone have any idea how to get access to/modify the style and/or selectors that get called on the Cancel button, for example (even if it's bad to do so and your app would certainly get rejected from the Apple store)?

Comment: You're going to get rejected if you use private APIs.

Comment: Well that's not always a concern, you know? Some people don't use the app store to deploy to their users!

Comment: True, but it is still a duplicate question.

Comment: Your best bet might be to use a custom view and send the email with a web service. Otherwise, if you want use the user's email account, I think you have to use the method Apple provides.